# cannot start empty OTP application from command line

Tags: erlang

I have created an OTP application skeleton with rebar:

```
$ rebar create-app appid=test
```

then I compiled it with `rebar compile`, and when I run

```
$ erl -pa ebin -s test
```

I get this error

```
{"init terminating in do_boot",{undef,[{test,start,[],[]},{init,start_it,1,[]},{init,start_em,1,[]}]}}
```

but if I call `start` from the shell it works:

```
$ erl -pa ebin

Erlang R15B01 (erts-5.9.1) [source] [smp:2:2] [async-threads:0] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.9.1  (abort with ^G)
1> application:start(test).
ok
```

How can I start the application from the OS command line?

EDIT:

I figured that I needed to run

```
$ erl -pa ebin -s application start test
```

now I am not getting any errors, but the app is still not getting started...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`erl -pa ebin/ -eval "application:start(test)"`

Since the `start` function in `test_app.erl` has arity 2 it is not possible to invoke it directly using the `erl` switch `-s` (or `-run`), only arity 0 or 1 are possible to invoke with those switches (see http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html).

You could add a wrapper function that in turn calls the `start/2`, but I think the `-eval` is more elegant.

Comment: I also think using the `-eval` flag is more elegant:)

Answer (score 3):

The `-s` flag assumes a list of arguments when one or more arguments are presented. So what `$ erl -pa ebin -s application start test` would do is calling `application:start([test])` which would not work as expected.

Here is a workaround (might not be the best solution):

Create a source file `src/test_init.erl` with the following content:

```
-module(test_init).

-compile(export_all).

init() ->
    application:start(test).
```

Then:

```
$ rebar compile
$ erl -pa ebin -s test_init init
```

Now the `test` application should be running:)